# global activity context in application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I am trying to implement a notification in my app based on some events. Everything is fine except the context of activity I need to trigger the notification.

I have a method to do some computation in non activity class and then I am invoking the notification class by passing the context but it does not seems like working well or I did something wrong.

Here is my code

Activity Class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_s);
    acti = sActivity.this;
    sSingleton.getInstance().init(sActivity.this);
  }
public static sActivity get(){
   return acti;
 }
 sActivity acti = null;
```

I am trying both ways through signalton or static method

Here is my signalton

```
    public class sSingleton {
    private static  sActivity appContext;

    private sSingleton(){}

    public void init(sActivity context){
        if(appContext == null){
            appContext = context;
        }
    }

    public static sActivity getContext(){
        return appContext;
    }

    public static sActivity get(){
        return getInstance().getContext();
    }

    private static sSingleton instance;

    public static sSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance == null ?
                (instance = new sSingleton()):
                instance;
    }
}
```

My notitification class

```
    public class sNotification {

    public sNotification(sActivity activity, ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.allData = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.allData = data;
        createNotification();
    }

    public void createNotification(){
          NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
                        .setContentTitle("New Data").setColor(Color.RED)
                        .setContentText(type + " : "+ value);
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("New Details");
        for(int i = 0; i < allData.size(); i++){
            inboxStyle.addLine(type + ": "+ value);
        }
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(sSignalton.get(), sActivity.class); //crashing here
               notificationIntent.putExtra("Notification", "Notify");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(sSignalton.get(), 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) sApplication.get().getSystemService(sActivity.get().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }

    sActivity activity;
    public static String TAG = "sNotification";
}
```

So the important thing is I do not know how to get the sActivity context here in notification class, I tried both signalton and through sActivity.get() static method but when application is destroyed, and notification condition gets true the application crashes. App crashes when app is not in foreground, only services are running.

Comment: Holding a static reference of an Activity context is so wrong. Perhaps you should re-think the design approach.

Comment: any suggestion to do it in clean manner...?

Comment: You should be able to pass a Service Context to the Notification.

Comment: Service Context? but how?

Comment: If you want to create a Notification from a Service instead of from an Activity, pass in the Service. Service is a Context.

Comment: Instead of Activity context, you should rely on Application context which can be retrieved via `getApplicationContext()` method call. It is safe to use Application context as it lives for the duration of  app's life-cycle.

Comment: but when I tried with application context, the app crashes at  manager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());...so i guess it needs activity context here...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to pass in the `Service`:

```
public void createNotification(Context context){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the global application context, which you can get from an `Activity` or a `Service` by calling `getApplicationContext()`. You can pass this `Context` to the class that creates the `Notifications`.

Remove all the singleton crap. That isn't necessary and is just going to make memory leaks.